# Stumped on Segfault: It looks like my comparator is trying to compare nodes out of scope

Tags: c++, scope, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

I am getting a segmentation fault. I believe it has something to do with how I am doing comparisons. I am stumped and new to C++.

The very last line, `pq.pop()` is the call that enters the stack trace and causes the failure. Nothing is printed out when executing ./a.out

```
class Node {
    public:

    Node() {}

    Node(int b) {
        bound = b;
    }

    Node(int b, Node * p) {
        bound = b;
        parent = p;
    }

    void addChild(Node& n) {
        n.parent = this;    
    }

    Node * parent;

    int bound;
};



class CompareNode {

public:
    bool operator()(Node *n, Node *o)
    {
        cout << "Comparing " << n->bound;
        cout << " to " << o-> bound <<endl;
        return n->bound > o->bound; 
    }
};
```

---

Under main

---

```
std::priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, CompareNode> pq;
Node* root = new Node();
Node* node;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  node = new Node(matrix[0][i], root);
  pq.push(node);
}

pq.pop();
```

---

**GDB**

---

```
(gdb) run
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004027e7 in void std::__pop_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode) ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000004027e7 in void std::__pop_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode) ()
#1  0x0000000000401e13 in void std::pop_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, CompareNode)
    ()
#2  0x0000000000401a11 in std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> >, CompareNode>::pop() ()
#3  0x00000000004015dc in main ()
```

Comment: How big is the matrix? Is the priority queue empty when `pop` is called?

Comment: You led me to the right answer. In the for loop n was equal to 0, which is why this was failing. I apologize, this is just lack of C++ experience on my part.

Comment: If you make an answer, I will give you the points if you care about such things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't often check necessary preconditions for you. If you call `pop` on an empty structure, the result is likely to be a crash. So that's the first place I'd look.

You might get this check in GCC using `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. It adds bound checking, iterator validation, etc. and it's a good set of training wheels in any case.